# Google Sheets - Submit button that sends cells value equal to 0

Tags: google-sheets, button

I have this script for a button that will send the values in certain cells from a given workbook and sheet to another sheet in a different workbook:

```
function Jan() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const fsh = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.ssid);
const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("sheet2");
const rgl = fsh.getRangeList(["H2","D4","I5","J5","F24","F25","F26","F27","F28"]);
let vs = rgl.getRanges().map(r => !r.isBlank()?r.getValue():rgl).filter(e => e);
if (vs.length == rgl.getRanges().length) {
dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 17).setValues([vs]);
} else {throw new Error ("REQUIRED FIELD IS EMPTY");
return;
}
}
```

As you can see, this script will give an error message when the cell is empty. However, it does the same when the value of a cell is equal to 0. Is there a way to avoid this, and make the script also submit 0 values, as 0 is a valid value to be sent?

Comment: Have you tried using `.getDisplayValue()` instead of `.getValue()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use .getDisplayValue()

If the `.getValue()` function does not recognize the value of 0, you may use `.getDisplayValue()` instead. To apply this function to your code, replace:

```
let vs = rgl.getRanges().map(r => !r.isBlank()?r.getValue():rgl).filter(e => e);
```

with:

```
let vs = rgl.getRanges().map(r => !r.isBlank() ? r.getDisplayValue() : rgl).filter(e => e);
```

### Side Note:

I noticed that in:

```
const rgl = fsh.getRangeList(["H2","D4","I5","J5","F24","F25","F26","F27","F28"]);
```

there are only 9 elements in the array. You may want to change:

```
dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 17).setValues([vs]);
```

to:

```
dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 9).setValues([vs]);
```

because you will get an error with regards to different array size/range.

### Reference:

- [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue)

Comment: Feel free to ask anything with respect to the answer posted above.

Comment: Thanks, that works exactly as I needed it. I guess I no longer need the error message, but, would you be able to help me get the script to give me an error message if H2 is different than the word "January" instead?

Comment: You're welcome! If I understand your follow up question correctly, I think you can use an if statement to compare of the value of H2 (using `getValue()` or `getDisplayValue()`) and compare it to your desired string (in your case "January"). If the values are different, then you can insert the error message function accordingly.

Comment: I have tried this, but I guess I just don't know how to write it (very new at this).

Comment: You may follow the script in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69961303/how-to-check-for-cell-value) since if you make another question for this, it will only be flagged as a duplicate post. You may also want to read [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) for if-else statement guide.

Comment: I thought you'd like to know that I managed to make it work. Thanks for all the help!